# Loading fonts from directory in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context, pandoc

I'm trying to load Montserrat & FontAwesome from a local directory in conTeXt, while parsing markdown w/ pandoc.

Adding the font with `mtxrun` doesn't seem to work:

```bash
export OSFONTDIR=$(pwd)/in/fonts/
mtxrun --script fonts --reload
```

even trying to list the fonts afterwards with `mtxrun --script fonts --list --all` is unsuccessful.

Also generating a typescript seems to fail resulting in a mysterious `pandoc: Error producing PDF`:

```
\usemodule[simplefonts][size=12pt]

\startenvironment montserrat
        \starttypescript[montserrat]
                \definefontsynonym [Sans] [file:Montserrat-Light.otf]
                \definefontsynonym [SansBold] [file:Montserrat-Bold.otf]
        \stoptypescript
\stopenvironment

\setmainfont[Sans]

\startenvironment fontawesome
        \starttypescript[fontawesome]
                \definefontsynonym [FA] [file:FontAwesome.otf]
        \stoptypescript
\stopenvironment
```

(with and without `[features=default]` or `.otf` on each `\definefontsynonym`) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can view my entire project on github: https://github.com/JKirchartz/resume/tree/context

Comment: To use fonts which are in the same directory as your document you have to use a `typescript` and the load the fonts by filename, e.g. `\definefontsynonym [Serif] [file:myfontregular.otf] [features=defult]`.

Comment: @Metafox I tried creating typescripts as you suggested, but still cannot produce a PDF, instead of an error w/ a line number I now get a cryptic "pandoc: Error producing PDF"

Answer (score 2):

The `pandoc: Error producing PDF` comes from your hilariously ill-formatted `JKirchartz-Resume.md`.  The usage of `\color` is completely wrong and the rest just looks like markup hell.

To workaround part of the problems, I've filed a [pull-request](https://github.com/JKirchartz/resume/pull/1) on your GitHub repo.  Here is the commit message.

> ```
> In response to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380902
>
> * Delete all the fonts.  They are all part of TeXlive and this do not have to
>   be bundled.
>
> * Make a typescript for the Montserrat fonts with the Light variant as default.
>
> * Remove the (wrong) typescript for FontAwesome and just use the built-in
>   symbol set.  Then adapt the definition of all the symbols.
>
> * The usage of \color in JKirchartz-Resume.md is completely wrong.  To obtain
>   the desired behaviour, monkey-patch it to be \directcolor.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look over this tonight -- I was converting this from a LaTeX project, and all that jazz worked over there.